# Column space and row space of a matrix of which $\det(A)=0$

Tags: linear-algebra

If $\det(A)$ not equal $0$, then $\operatorname{Col} A = \operatorname{Row}A$? $A$ is diagonalizable? Thank you a lot.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE.  Thank you for your question.  It will help us answer it if you give the context of the problem, where it comes from.  Also, please define your terms -- What is Col A?  Lastly, please share what you've tried so far so that we don't repeat things you already know.

Answer (score 1):

If you're referring to the determinant of $A$, then I'm assuming $A$ is square (of, say, size $n \times n$).  Then $\det A \ne 0$ if and only if $\mathrm{Col}\, A = \mathbb{R}^n$ if and only if $\mathrm{Row}\, A = \mathbb{R}^n$ (if you're working over some other field, say $\mathbb{C}$, then replace $\mathbb{R}$ by that field).  So $\det A \ne 0$ does imply that the column space and row space of $A$ are equal.

On the other hand, the determinant of $A$ gives you no information about whether or not the matrix is diagonalizable.

Comment: This helped me a lot. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

If $\det A\not=0$ then $A$ is invertible but not necessary diagonalisable: for example
$$A=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
1&1\\
0&1
\end{array}\right)$$
is invertible since $\det A=1\not=0$ but not diagonalisable.